# SQL help - Summary with data from values listed

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to figure this out, but am stuck... I am looking to calculate distinct emails from a system that holds email address from multiple companies, and want to summarize by the companies that are values within a column..

[image: sample data set]

**Current query:**

```
select count(*), count(EMAIL), count(distinct EMAIL), count(company) from "email_db" 
GROUP BY(company);
```

I can not get the company values to show up, just the counts, so ideally the results would be:

```
Company XYZ     2
Company ABC     1
```

What statement should replace count(company) to show the actual values within the field to summarize it by?

```
 select count(*), count(EMAIL), count(distinct EMAIL), count(company) from "email_db" 
    GROUP BY(company);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated to get me to the correct results... This is simple enough to do in Excel.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Snowflake @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to add `company` to the `select`:

```
select company, count(*), count(EMAIL), count(distinct EMAIL) 
from "email_db" 
group by company;
```

The three columns are:

- `count(*)` -- number of matching rows for the company, even if `email` is null.
- `count(email)` -- number of matching rows where `email` is not null.
- `count(distinct email)` -- number of different emails.

Comment: Awesome, getting there... How would I go about showing the quantity of duplicates across the companies? Meaning, I would like to calculate for the Companies, how many email addresses are duplicates. So.....

Company 1               Company 2             Company 3
email_address 1       email_address_1      email_address_1           = 3
email_address 2       email_address_2                                            =2

Comment: @eclecticwax . . . That would be a very different question and should be asked as a *new* question.